# Was Ruben Diaz presumptively defeated?

Tags: united-states, election, voting

Ruben Diaz appears to have been defeated in the primary. Ruben Diaz is a highly conservative Democrat who rolled eyebrows by running in what is said to be the bluest district. I am calling the race with Ritchie Torres because he has received over two times as many votes as Diaz. They have called NY-16 for Bowman. So, has the race been called for Ritchie Torres or does it need to wait for the mail-in ballots to be counted? (If not, could it be safely called?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Calling" a race just means a pundit is saying that the result is now not in doubt, even if it is mathematically possible for the result to be changed.

So in an imaginary constituency with 100 voters and two candidates.  If after  75 votes have been counted, candidate A has 45 votes and B has 30 votes, a pundit might "call" the election, saying "(in my judgement) the probability of B winning is negligible as the chance the last 25 votes splitting 4-21 is or more is essentially zero"

Different pundits may call the election at different times, it is a matter of judgement.  The mail-in votes do need to be counted for the final certified result.  And indeed, 12 hours later with all precincts reporting, the results point to a clear victory for Ritchie Torres with nearly 30% of the votes, Blake second, and Diaz third.

Absentee votes will be counted later.

Comment: I am calling the race for Ruben Torrez.